# Emulate bidirectional scroll using hotkey + trackball

Tags: xorg, mouse, scrolling, wayland

I've built a custom keyboard with a trackball under my thumb and I want to map a scroll behavior in such way that when I press a shortcut (like left alt) and rotate the ball, it should behave like a scroll. I'm using Xorg here, but I'd be very interested in seing solutions for both X and Wayland (if the solution would involve display server).

Comment: As there are no answers: What exactly do you want to scroll? You can configure your window manager to scroll the virtual viewport, for example. If you want your trackball to emulate a mousewheel when used together with a key, you'll likely have to fiddle with some driver (either on the hardware level, or on the X resp. Wayland level). But as you built the keyboard yourself, maybe you are already using a custom driver.

Comment: I'm not using a custom driver. In fact the trackball is just embedded Logitech M570 trackball's ball into Kinesis Advantage. I want to use it as a scroll for all the content of my applications - like scrolling the code text area or pages in a web browser. I want it to behave just like mouse wheel when rotating vertical and like horizontal wheel when rotating horizontally. The idea is to have just one input device - keyboard with a trackball and being able to just scroll content using the ball while holding some modifier key. Is it clear now? :)

Answer (score 3):

## Emulate vertical and horizontal scrolling using `libinput`

The `evdev` driver from *dirkt's* answer only supports vertical scrolling emulation. If you (like me) also want to scroll horizontally, the `libinput` driver can be used to do that:

1. The details are in the manpage for `libinput(4)`:

   > **Option "ScrollButton" "int"**
   >
   > Designates a button as scroll button. If the **ScrollMethod** is **button** and the button is  logically  held  down, x/y axis movement is converted into scroll events.
   >
   > **Option "ScrollMethod" "string"**
   >
   > Enables  a scroll method. Permitted values are **none, twofinger, edge, button**.  Not all devices support all options, if an option is unsupported, the default scroll option for this device is used
2. For example:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Some Trackball"
     # ... Stuff to match your trackball, see xorg.conf(5)
     Driver "libinput"
     Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
     Option "ScrollButton" "4" # Or whatever button suits your needs
   EndSection
   ```

Comment: Try [this temporary with `xinput`](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/349837).

Answer (score 0):

**Simulate mouse wheel with trackball**

You can either use existing configuration options of drivers that do something similar to what you want, or write your own driver.

The *Logitech M570* is a wireless trackball with an USB-receiver. That means it will show up as a  [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) device, and mouse events will be made available via the [input](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/) layer in the kernel, and can read from the corresponding `/dev/event` device.

The X driver in turn uses the `evdev` driver to read events from this layer, and turns them into X events. I'm not familiar with Wayland, but I assume it will work similarly there.

1) The `evdev` driver already contains options to emulate a mousewheel on a trackball, see `man evdev`. The most important ones are

> **Option "EmulateWheel" "boolean"**
>
> Enable/disable "wheel" emulation.  Wheel emulation means emulating button press/release events when the mouse is moved while  a specific real button is pressed.  Wheel button events (typically buttons 4 and 5) are usually used for scrolling. Wheel emulation is useful for getting wheel-like behaviour with trackballs.
>
> **Option "EmulateWheelButton" "integer"**
>
> Specifies which button must be held down to enable wheel emulation mode.  While this button is down, X and/or Y pointer movement will generate button press/release events as specified for the XAxisMapping and YAxisMapping settings. If the button is 0 and  EmulateWheel is on, any motion of the device is converted into wheel events. Default: 4.

So this works using a trackball button instead of keyboard shortcut (because the driver only sees events from the mouse, not from the keyboard), and will convert *movement* into wheel events, and not *rotation*.

2) Write your own driver by modifying several existing ones. You will need to combine the drivers for the keyboard and the mouse, so wheel emulation can be triggered by keypresses.

The source code for the **kernel input layer** is in `drivers/input` in the kernel tree.

The source code for the **evdev** X driver is in [xorg/driver/xf86-input-evdev/tree/src/evdev.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-evdev/tree/src/evdev.c).

The keyboard driver depends on what type of keyboard you used.