# How to use Mouse Wheel Emulation?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, input, scrolling

I have a pointing device without a scroll wheel, but I'd like to be able to scroll with it, perhaps by holding down a key and dragging.  I've seen a few threads about similar topics, but none of the solutions appear to work.

Comment: have you tried the solution in https://superuser.com/q/376692/685512 ?  see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369919/222377

Comment: You should specify the name and version of your Linux distribution, as some distributions have transitioned to `libinput`-based X input drivers and others have not. This has a big impact on how to configure mouse wheel emulation.

Comment: @telcoM I'm using Arch

Comment: Arch might be using `libinput`, or it might not. Run `xinput`, note the `id=#` number of your pointing device, and add the output of a corresponding `xinput list-props #" command to your question post. Also, does your pointing device have any extra buttons you would be able to dedicate to wheel emulation? I don't know of a way to use keyboard keys.

Comment: Why not change for a newer mouse?

Comment: @techno IIRC this wasn't about a mouse

Comment: @techno Newer mice (including some really nice ones) sometimes lack the scroll wheel and the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 3):

I have a mouse with no scroll wheel, so I configured it to scroll by moving the mouse while holding down the middle button.

Previously, I did it by pasting the following into the terminal on startup.

```
xinput --set-prop 'Areson USB Device' 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' 1
xinput --set-prop 'Areson USB Device' 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Button' 2
xinput --set-prop 'Areson USB Device' 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout' 100
```

After upgrading from Linux Mint 18 to 19, the above no longer worked. Instead, I had to do

```
xinput --set-prop 'Areson USB Device' 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0 0 1
```

The specifics may differ. For example, your device name will probably be different. You can figure it out by doing `xinput list`. You can figure out whether you are using `evdev` or `libinput` by running `xinput list-props 12` where 12 is the number shown next to your mouse when you run `xinput list`.

Comment: Thanks... this worked great for my classic Logitech TrackMan FX T-RA17 under Xubuntu. I put the line in a file under /etc/X11/Xsession.d/

Comment: If I want to use something else instead of the middle button (like say Alt, or the forward mouse button), how would I go about doing that?